# Strongly Connected Components

Tags: graph-theory

A strongly connected component in a digraph is defined as a subgraph where every vertex is reachable from every other vertex. I'm wondering if a seemingly related property exists for undirected graphs where every node in the subgraph would be directly connected to every other node in the subgraph?

Comment: If by "directly connected" you mean "by a single edge", then your subgraph is a complete graph. Such subgraphs are called *cliques*. If you don't require single edges between every pair of vertices, but rather just paths, such a subgraph is called *connected*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, a (undirected) connected graph is a graph in which a path exists from one vertex to any other vertex. But a graph need not be complete (as in your description) in order to be connected.

Answer (score 0):

If by "directly connected" you mean "connected by a path" then you're just describing [connected components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29).

Comment: What I'm describing would be a connected component, but what I'm interested in are subgraphs where each node in the subgraph is connected to every other node in the subgraph. An example with five nodes would result in a graph looking very much like a pentagram circumscribed in a pentagon.

Comment: The kind of graphs you are describing are the [complete graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph). Complete graphs appearing as a subgraph of another graph are called [cliques](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_(graph_theory)).